# Как задать размер Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть окно, в котором присутствуют Treeview и ScrollBar. Хотел создать Frame так, чтобы Дерево и Скролл находились в нём, но столкнулся с одной проблемой. Никак не получается задать размер Frame. Помогите, пожалуйста, осуществить это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
...
```